# Gatsby Stripe Checkout - multiple quantities

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm following this Gatsby guide - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/ecommerce-tutorial/

I would like to modify this code to allow the user to change the number of items they can purchase.

Following this React guide - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html - I am adding an `<input>` field to allow a quantity to be chosen.

I then want to pass the value to here - `items: [{ sku: "XXXXXXXX", quantity: 1 }]`

The error I get is **TypeError: _this.handleInputChange is undefined** on the line `this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);`

Any pointers would be great, thanks.

```
import React from "react"

const Checkout = class extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numberOfItems: 2
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }  

  componentDidMount() {
    this.stripe = window.Stripe("XXXXXXX")
  }

  async redirectToCheckout(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { error } = await this.stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{ sku: "XXXXXXXX", quantity: 1 }],
      successUrl: `http://localhost:8000/thank-you`,
      cancelUrl: `http://localhost:8000/`,
    })

    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error:", error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>

        <label>
          Number to buy
        <input
          name="numberOfItems"
          type="number"
          value={this.state.numberOfItems}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </label>

        <button
          onClick={event => this.redirectToCheckout(event)}
        >
          Buy Now
        </button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Checkout
```

Update: I went with a different solution in the end:

```
import React from "react"

const Checkout = class extends React.Component {

  state = { count: 1 }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  }

  handleDecrement = () => {
    if(this.state.count > 1){
      this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.stripe = window.Stripe("")
  }

  async redirectToCheckout(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { error } = await this.stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      items: [{ sku: "", quantity: this.state.count }],
      successUrl: `http://localhost:8000/thank-you`,
      cancelUrl: `http://localhost:8000/`,
    })

    if (error) {
      console.warn("Error:", error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>

        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</button>

        <div>
          {this.state.count}
        </div>

        <button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</button>

        <button
          onClick={event => this.redirectToCheckout(event)}
          >
          Buy
        </button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Checkout
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function `handleInputChange` in your class.

I believe you forgot to implement it in your class, for example:

```
import React from 'react';

const Checkout = class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numberOfItems: 2,
      inputValue
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          Number to buy
          <input
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
      </div>
    );
}
```